# Adwords Conversion OnClick

Tags: onclick, google-ads-api

How can I make Adwords conversion OnClick **without improt from analytics**?

I mean, when visitor come to my landing page nothing happens, only when visitor click on specific link it will counted as new conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate code from AdWords in advanced section. Then code should looks like this:

```
<!-- Google Code for XXXXXX Conversion Page
In your html page, add the snippet and call
goog_report_conversion when someone clicks on the
chosen link or button. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  goog_snippet_vars = function() {
    var w = window;
    w.google_conversion_id = XXXXXX;
    w.google_conversion_label = "XXXXXXXX";
    w.google_remarketing_only = false;
  }
  // DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
  goog_report_conversion = function(url) {
    goog_snippet_vars();
    window.google_conversion_format = "3";
    window.google_is_call = true;
    var opt = new Object();
    opt.onload_callback = function() {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  }
  var conv_handler = window['google_trackConversion'];
  if (typeof(conv_handler) == 'function') {
    conv_handler(opt);
  }
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js">
</script>
```

All the hints you can find in Adwords and Google support.

Answer (score 0):

this will help https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6095821?hl=en they have a video guide